# Cesium: Custom material on a Rectangle Entity

Tags: cesiumjs

I am trying to add an Entity whose has several varying properties such as material (alpha, mostly) and rotation. RectangleGraphics has rotation covered, and works when I set the material to represent a texture.

```
viewer.entities.add({ 
  name: 'Site Layer', 
  rectangle: { 
    coordinates: rectangle, 
    material: 'Image.jpg', 
    rotation: Cesium.Math.toRadians(13)     
  }
});
```

However, when I tried to implement transparency by using a custom Material (using https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium/issues/2484) it shows up as a white texture instead of the desired result ... something like:

```
material = new Cesium.Material({
    fabric : {
        type : 'Color',
            uniforms : {
                image : 'Image.jpg',
                alpha : 0.5
            }
             components : {
                 diffuse : 'texture2D(image, materialInput.st).rgb',
                 alpha : 'texture2D(image, materialInput.st).a * alpha'
            }
        }
    }
);
viewer.entities.add({ 
  rectangle: { 
    coordinates: rectangle, 
    material: material,
    rotation: Cesium.Math.toRadians(13)     
  }
});
```

Reading the docs, the material in rectangle seems to be a Cesium.MaterialProperty rather than Cesium.Material ... does that mean I can't simply assign a Material to a Rectangle? And if not, can I somehow wrap the Material inside a custom MaterialProperty to make it work?

And for curiosity, why is the functional difference between Material and MaterialProperty?

p.s. GroundPrimitive doesn't work for me because one of the main browsers I need to support (Safari) reports GroundPrimitives.isSupported = false

Also posted here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cesium-dev/1IPjHD7G_NA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hannah answered this on the forums.  I'll copy her answer here below, but first I'll add my own notes on why `MaterialProperty` is different from `Material`.

The `Property` version, like all [Cesium Entity Properties](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/Property.html?classFilter=property), is meant to describe how the definition of something changes over time when Cesium animates.  For example, a `MaterialProperty` could indicate a solid color during one time interval, and a striped material during a separate time interval.  The actual underlying `Material` may be destroyed and a replacement one created during animation as a result of this.

For your case, if you really need a custom-built Material, your best option currently is to avoid the Entity API and its time-dynamic properties, and just use a graphics primitive with the `Material` class directly.  But as Hannah points out, you don't need that for simple image alpha blending.  Hannah writes:

---

This should be fixed in the upcoming release (1.16)
You can use this code to make a translucent image:

```
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer');
viewer.entities.add({
    rectangle: {
        coordinates: Cesium.Rectangle.fromDegrees(-125,30,-110,40),
        material: new Cesium.ImageMaterialProperty({
            image: '../images/Cesium_Logo_Color.jpg',
            alpha: 0.5
        }),
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation on Properties. For the purpose of a rotated image with alpha this works, though in the long term I want to add a bump map to it also, so I tried a custom primitive but it doesn't seem to work on various CallbackProperty which I was attaching to slider values.I guess that's the one thing I also want from the Entity system. I tried implementing a custom MaterialProperty such as this example:  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cesium-dev/L05gq_SZ4uI, but in I don't see a Material being returned for a given time.