# How to create a dashed arrow in Cesium

Tags: glsl, cesiumjs

Cesium has solid arrows ([PolylineArrow](https://cesium.com/docs/cesiumjs-ref-doc/PolylineArrowMaterialProperty.html)) and dashed lines ([PolylineDash](https://cesium.com/docs/cesiumjs-ref-doc/PolylineDashMaterialProperty.html?classFilter=polylined)). I want to combine the two to make a PolylineDashArrow (An Arrow with a Dash Fill, or a dash line with an arrow head).

It sounds like this should be possible using Cesium's [Fabric](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium/wiki/Fabric#combining-materials). Though I think I need to add a GLSL like the ones for [arrow](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium/blob/1.65/Source/Shaders/Materials/PolylineArrowMaterial.glsl) and [dash](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium/blob/1.65/Source/Shaders/Materials/PolylineDashMaterial.glsl). (The Fabric page doesn't say anything about how to add a custom GLSL to use for the source)

This seems like something that should be really easy to do but I can't find any information on anyone else trying to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, it should have been straightforward.  But there's a small catch in that you don't want the dashes interrupting the arrow head itself.  The arrow head should always be solid, or it looks wrong.

The biggest problem I ran into is that the dash material doesn't just mark the gaps between dashes as transparent, it actually marks them for discard.  The good news is this is done with a Boolean value (not a raw `discard` keyword) that can be tricked into becoming false again, to keep those gaps from interrupting the arrow head.

So I had to cheat a bit to disable the dashMaterial's discard, but I got it to work.

Here's what I ended up with:  [Sandcastle demo of dashed arrow](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/#c=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).

The code for that demo looks like this:

```
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer');
var scene = viewer.scene;

// Create sample polyline primitive.
var polylines = scene.primitives.add(new Cesium.PolylineCollection());
var polyline = polylines.add({
    positions : Cesium.PolylinePipeline.generateCartesianArc({
        positions : Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegreesArray([-110.0, 42.0,
                                                        -85.0, 36.0,
                                                        -100.0, 25.0,
                                                        -77.0, 12.0])
    }),
    width : 15.0
});

// Assign a new fabric material blend of arrow and dashes.
polyline.material = new Cesium.Material({
    fabric : {
        materials : {
            // The arrowMaterial provides the color and overall shape.
            arrowMaterial : {
                type : 'PolylineArrow',
                uniforms : {
                    color : Cesium.Color.YELLOW
                }
            },
            // The dashMaterial will punch holes in the arrowMaterial.
            // Uniforms could be added to control the dash parameters.
            dashMaterial : {
                type : 'PolylineDash',
            },
            // "headMaterial" is copy-paste of the arrow head size code, written to alpha.
            // It is used to mask out the dashes, to keep them from destroying the arrow head.
            // A small tail is included behind the arrow head, to keep it from becoming a triangle.
            headMaterial : {
                source :
                'czm_material czm_getMaterial(czm_materialInput materialInput) { \n' +
                '    czm_material material = czm_getDefaultMaterial(materialInput); \n' +
                '    vec2 st = materialInput.st; \n' +
                '#ifdef GL_OES_standard_derivatives \n' +
                // Original multiplier "10.0" changed to "15.0" to add short tail to head.
                '    float base = 1.0 - abs(fwidth(st.s)) * 15.0 * czm_pixelRatio; \n' +
                '#else \n' +
                '    float base = 0.975; // 2.5% of the line will be the arrow head \n' +
                '#endif \n' +
                '    material.alpha = 1.0 - smoothstep(base - 0.0001, base, st.s); \n' +
                '    return material; \n' +
                '} \n'
            }
        },
        // Finally, the "alpha" contains a cheat, where we undo czm_discard from the dashMaterial.
        components : {
            diffuse : 'arrowMaterial.diffuse',
            alpha : 'arrowMaterial.alpha * (1.0 - (headMaterial.alpha * (1.0 - dashMaterial.alpha))); czm_discard = false'
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Apparently cesium.com showcase =/= sandcastle.cesium.com. So that's why the GLSL wasn't compiling. X3 Now I'm able to splice together the arrow and dash GLSL to keep the full functionality of the dash for the base. It seems the other issue I was having is that Primitives =/= Properties, so trying to use it as part of an Entity Polyline was also causing rendering issues (Expects a PolylineMaterialProperty). So now I need to learn how to elevate it to the Entity level. This was exactly what I was looking for. :3 Thanks for the help.

Comment: If you build Sandcastle locally, there is a "Development" tab that is not published to the website directly.  This tab shows graphics-primitive-level examples, where the main tabs show Entity-level examples.

Comment: I noticed that the sandcastle I was originally testing on was using Cesium 1.1, and that's why it didn't work. Seems something changed between version 1.6 and 1.65. I get errors on the older versions.

Comment: Do you really mean `1.6` and not `1.60`?  There's a four- to five-year difference between those versions.  Polyline dashes were added sometime in the last couple years I think, they might not have been an option in `1.6`.

Comment: I meant `1.60`. I was getting `czm_pixelRatio not defined` at render time.

Comment: Yeah there was some recent internally-breaking change with DPI and pixelRatio.  I would look at the source code from the `1.60` tag instead of master for that.  Or better yet, upgrade your Cesium version if you can, so you don't write new code against an API that already changed.

Comment: Yeay, I already upgraded to 1.65. To get my own Material Property to work, do I need to add it to `CzmlDataSource.processMaterialProperty`? I was hoping to update (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34001821/cesium-custom-material-on-a-rectangle-entity) with an answer on how to actually add a custom material property, but `ShaderProgram._setUniforms` fails at `e[o.name]()`, and I don't see how to change/fix what it is being fed.

Comment: nvm, somehow I was missing an 's' despite the fact that the s isn't missing in the answer I posted.

Answer (score 2):

A variant on emackey's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59687432/6893866). Alot more manual since it is merging the Arrow and Dash GLSL instead of using the simple Fabric mixing (And adding a line in the arrowhead logic to lock in the color used). This allows use of the dash multi-color effect. Here is the sandcastle [demo](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/#c=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), and code used below. (Note that this is still just a material primitive, and can't be used as a MaterialProperty in Entities)

```
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer');
var scene = viewer.scene;

var PolylineDashArrowSource = '\
#ifdef GL_OES_standard_derivatives\n\
#extension GL_OES_standard_derivatives : enable\n\
#endif\n\
\n\
uniform vec4 color;\n\
uniform vec4 gapColor;\n\
uniform float dashLength;\n\
uniform float dashPattern;\n\
\n\
varying float v_polylineAngle;\n\
varying float v_width;\n\
\n\
const float maskLength = 16.0;\n\
\n\
mat2 rotate(float rad) {\n\
    float c = cos(rad);\n\
    float s = sin(rad);\n\
    return mat2(\n\
        c, s,\n\
        -s, c\n\
    );\n\
}\n\
\n\
float getPointOnLine(vec2 p0, vec2 p1, float x)\n\
{\n\
    float slope = (p0.y - p1.y) / (p0.x - p1.x);\n\
    return slope * (x - p0.x) + p0.y;\n\
}\n\
\n\
czm_material czm_getMaterial(czm_materialInput materialInput)\n\
{\n\
    czm_material material = czm_getDefaultMaterial(materialInput);\n\
\n\
    vec2 pos = rotate(v_polylineAngle) * gl_FragCoord.xy;\n\
\n\
    // Get the relative position within the dash from 0 to 1\n\
    float dashPosition = fract(pos.x / (dashLength * czm_pixelRatio));\n\
    // Figure out the mask index.\n\
    float maskIndex = floor(dashPosition * maskLength);\n\
    // Test the bit mask.\n\
    float maskTest = floor(dashPattern / pow(2.0, maskIndex));\n\
    vec4 fragColor = (mod(maskTest, 2.0) < 1.0) ? gapColor : color;\n\
\n\
    vec2 st = materialInput.st;\n\
\n\
#ifdef GL_OES_standard_derivatives\n\
    float base = 1.0 - abs(fwidth(st.s)) * 10.0 * czm_pixelRatio;\n\
#else\n\
    float base = 0.975; // 2.5% of the line will be the arrow head\n\
#endif\n\
\n\
    vec2 center = vec2(1.0, 0.5);\n\
    float ptOnUpperLine = getPointOnLine(vec2(base, 1.0), center, st.s);\n\
    float ptOnLowerLine = getPointOnLine(vec2(base, 0.0), center, st.s);\n\
\n\
    float halfWidth = 0.15;\n\
    float s = step(0.5 - halfWidth, st.t);\n\
    s *= 1.0 - step(0.5 + halfWidth, st.t);\n\
    s *= 1.0 - step(base, st.s);\n\
\n\
    float t = step(base, materialInput.st.s);\n\
    t *= 1.0 - step(ptOnUpperLine, st.t);\n\
    t *= step(ptOnLowerLine, st.t);\n\
\n\
    // Find the distance from the closest separator (region between two colors)\n\
    float dist;\n\
    if (st.s < base)\n\
    {\n\
        if (fragColor.a < 0.005) {   // matches 0/255 and 1/255\n\
            discard;\n\
        }\n\
        float d1 = abs(st.t - (0.5 - halfWidth));\n\
        float d2 = abs(st.t - (0.5 + halfWidth));\n\
        dist = min(d1, d2);\n\
    }\n\
    else\n\
    {\n\
        fragColor = color;\n\
        float d1 = czm_infinity;\n\
        if (st.t < 0.5 - halfWidth && st.t > 0.5 + halfWidth)\n\
        {\n\
            d1 = abs(st.s - base);\n\
        }\n\
        float d2 = abs(st.t - ptOnUpperLine);\n\
        float d3 = abs(st.t - ptOnLowerLine);\n\
        dist = min(min(d1, d2), d3);\n\
    }\n\
\n\
    vec4 outsideColor = vec4(0.0);\n\
    vec4 currentColor = mix(outsideColor, fragColor, clamp(s + t, 0.0, 1.0));\n\
    vec4 outColor = czm_antialias(outsideColor, fragColor, currentColor, dist);\n\
\n\
    outColor = czm_gammaCorrect(outColor);\n\
    material.diffuse = outColor.rgb;\n\
    material.alpha = outColor.a;\n\
    return material;\n\
}';

var PolylineDashArrowType = 'PolylineDashArrow';
Cesium.Material[PolylineDashArrowType] = PolylineDashArrowType;
Cesium.Material._materialCache.addMaterial(PolylineDashArrowType, {
    strict: true,
    fabric : {
        type : PolylineDashArrowType,
        uniforms: {
            color : Cesium.Color.WHITE,
            gapColor : Cesium.Color.TRANSPARENT,
            dashLength : 16.0,
            dashPattern : 255.0
        },
        source : PolylineDashArrowSource
    },
    translucent : true
});

var polylines = scene.primitives.add(new Cesium.PolylineCollection());
var polyline1 = polylines.add({
    positions : Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegreesArray([-110.0, 42.0,
                                                    -85.0, 36.0,
                                                    -100.0, 25.0,
                                                    -77.0, 12.0]),
    width : 16,
    material : Cesium.Material.fromType(PolylineDashArrowType, {
        color: Cesium.Color.RED,
        gapColor: Cesium.Color.TRANSPARENT
    })
});

var polyline2 = polylines.add({
    positions : Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegreesArray([-130.0, 42.0,
                                                    -105.0, 36.0,
                                                    -120.0, 25.0,
                                                    -97.0, 12.0]),
    width : 16,
    material : Cesium.Material.fromType(PolylineDashArrowType, {
        color: Cesium.Color.RED,
        gapColor: Cesium.Color.YELLOW
    })
});
```

And [here](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/#c=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) is another version of it using Entities.

Comment: Seems like you're close to being able to open a PR for this into Cesium, if you wanted to contribute it.  That would be a stepping stone to get it into the Entity and CZML layers, perhaps.